# updating database attribute based on some calculated logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is what I am willing to do:

- ..save into database (signup_history's table) the value inside created_at + session timeout defined with ENV['SESSION_EXPIRE']
- ..then, when a user signs out (i.e in the SessionsController#destroy action), override session_end column with current_time (i.e. Time.now)

**SessionsController#destroy**

```
def destroy
  clear_all_sessions current_user.id
  reset_session
  redirect_to root_path
end


def save_signup_history(member_id)
  SignupHistory.create(
    member_id: member_id,
    email_id: @member.email,
    ip: request.remote_ip, # Useful for Remote IP
    accept_language: request.headers["Accept-Language"],
    ua: request.headers["User-Agent"],
    login_location: get_ip_location(request.remote_ip), # returns remote login location
  )
end
```

**This is what I have done but am confused of my logic**

```
def session_end_method
  if session.destroy
    Time.now
  else
    SignupHistory.created_at + ENV['SESSION_EXPIRE']
  end
end

def update_signup_history
  SignupHistory.update(
    session_end: session_end_method # call the method that is doing the logic so the value can be updated into the cell.
  )
end
```

But this doesn't work and I can agree its not a robust solution. Can someone please help me? All I want to do is update the column session_end in the database based on my explanation.

As you can see from the picture below, session_end aint saving anything in the database.

[image: session_end]

Comment: You may want to approach this the other way and instead have some Javascript making XHR calls every X minutes from the client's browser in order to give you the opportunity to log each of those events. Then, you can simply know when the user was _not_ using your website by checking the "logged-in and displaying the page" events. This period XHR call could send relevant data like a timestamp, the IP of the client, maybe the current page displayed, etc.

Comment: @MrYoshiji can you help me with a solution? Any code do deal with that?

Comment: To extend my suggestion: You can also implement a "compressor" script to convert those raw events into period of activity by finding consecutive events for the same user.

Comment: A simple AJAX call inside a setTimeout defined in your application layout - only if the user is signed in I presume - to a controller endpoint storing this event should do the trick.